# 24 hour clock not formatting date

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdateformatter

Below is what I have.

```
NSString *mss = @"2014-06-25 18:03:59.61";
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[f setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:mss];
NSDateFormatter *f2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLog(@"date==%@", date);
[f2 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm a"];
NSString *s = [[f2 stringFromDate:date] uppercaseString];
NSLog(@"s===%@--", s);
```

I have 2 iPhone with **iOS 7 latest versions**.

1. iPhone 4s >> time format I have is 24 hour format.
2. iPhone 5s >> time format I have is 12 hour format.

Now when I tried to run above code it works fine in iPhone 5s (12 hr format), but gives 24 hour format date for iPhone 4s (24 hr format).

**iPhone 4s >> 24-hr format**

```
date==2014-06-25 15:03:59 +0000
s===25/06/2014 18:03--
               ^^^^^ this is problem
```

**iPhone 5s >> 12-hr format**

```
date==2014-06-25 03:03:59 pm +0000
s===25/06/2014 06:03 PM--
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

---

### Answer

The BIG problem was I was missing below line.

```
[f2 setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

I had to set both formatter using same timezone.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `yyyy` and not `YYYY`?

Comment: Check out your date and time format under `General->Date & Time` section

Comment: @trojanfoe : thanks for pointing out that... still it is giving same problem...

Comment: What version of iOS are these devices running (this is more important than the hardware model)?

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre : what do you meant? are you telling me to change by time setting in iPhone? please don't tell me that...

Comment: @trojanfoe : both have latest iOS 7 versions...

Comment: @FahimParkar that only the way. As per my info NSDateFormate give system selected 24 or 12 hour format. No matter in which format you want.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre : I will DIE if this is fact... I will report this BUG to Apple...

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Not true; see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: @trojanfoe Please provide some working sample on this. It will be helpful for everyone if it works.

Comment: @FahimParkar How about if you set the timezone and locale in both formatters?

Comment: From Apple documentation: `In iOS, the user can override the default AM/PM versus 24-hour time setting. This may cause NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format string you set.`

Comment: @trojanfoe : can you see akk answer? his code is like me, but its working...

Comment: @trojanfoe : I will post answer... but I still can't believe this is problem...

Comment: @FahimParkar I don't see how that's correct.  Did you try setting locale and timezone in both formatters?

Comment: @downvoter : please put comment for downvote...

Comment: @trojanfoe : [could you please take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363867/iphone-6-plus-giving-same-output-even-data-is-updated)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *sel_date= @"2014-06-25 18:03:59.61";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sel_date];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *dateWithNewFormat = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"datestring ==== %@",dateWithNewFormat);
```

Output is

```
datestring ==== 25/06/2014 06:03 PM
```

Comment: simple question... your code is working but what is difference between mine and your code?

Comment: that give same output with OP datestring ==== 25/06/2014 06:03 PM

Comment: change the "YYYY" to "yyyy"

Comment: @FahimParkar I think the key to this solution is that the formatter is being re-used with a different date format and therefore the locale and timezone are common in both cases.  I have been asking you try setting the same locale and timezone for some time now...

Comment: @trojanfoe : ahh I understand now... f2 was missing `[f setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];`... Right?

Comment: @FahimParkar Yes; and timezone is probably important too.